# Lightning Component - recordID causing error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am creating a Lightning Component (Aura) to create a child record from the parent record. The basic component worked up until I added the "recordId="{!v.recordId}"" line after `<lightning:recordEditForm`. I just get an error message now that says `[object object]`. Can anyone spot what I have wrong here?

The parent object is "Employee__c" and the child object is "Employee_Session__c".

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="disabled" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="saved" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="showSpinner" type="Boolean" default="true" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}">
        <lightning:spinner />
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!!v.saved}">
        <lightning:recordEditForm
            recordId="{!v.recordId}"
            onload="{!c.handleLoad}"
            onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
            onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
            objectApiName="Employee_Session__c"
            >
            <!-- the messages component is for error messages -->
            <lightning:messages />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Employee__c" value="{!v.recordId}" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Intro_with_Compliance_Verbiage__c" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Core__c" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Voluntary_Benefits__c" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Conclusion__c" />
            <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                <lightning:button disabled="{!v.disabled}" variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Create Session" />
            </div>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            <p>Saved! New record id is {!v.recordId}</p>
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

[image]

Comment: why you  parent  `v.recordid` added in` recordId="{!v.recordId}"` for  child record form `lightning:recordEditForm` , what is your use case?  that's why cmp gets confused because your parent component implemented by `force:hasRecordId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to create a record of the child object i.e. `Employee_Session__c` and passing the record id of your parent object `Employee__c` to your form as **recordId** attribute will have the current record id.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm
            recordId="{!v.recordId}"
            onload="{!c.handleLoad}"
            onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
            onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
            objectApiName="Employee_Session__c"
            >
```

> As you are creating a record, you don't need the recordId attribute in
>   your form markup definition. your markup should be like this:-

```
<lightning:recordEditForm
                onload="{!c.handleLoad}"
                onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
                onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
                objectApiName="Employee_Session__c"
                >
```

Read more here:- [Aura Component
Record Edit Form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation)